# Cypress cy.write push new items to an array throws "push is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, cypress

Using the same code from https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile.html#Flags

```
const filename = '/path/to/list.json'

cy.readFile(filename).then((list) => {
  list.push({ item: 'example' })
  // write the merged array
  cy.writeFile(filename, list)
})
```

#system throws:
list.push is not a function

```
fixture file:/path/to/list.json
{
    "details": {
        "name": "abc",
        "age": 20
    }
}
```

expecting the list.json output as

```
{
    "details": {
        "name": "abc",
        "age": 20
    },
    "item": "example"
}
```

Has anyone tried to append an existing JSON file with the above code snap?
If so please share with me your experience.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`.push()` is for arrays, but you have an object in your JSON file. Use `list.item ='example';` to set a new property on an object.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
For single value ``` list.item ='example' ```, works .
-
Please assist with an array, provide a code snapshot if you can.
Example:
list.push({ item: 'example', item2: 'example2' , item3: 'example3'})
Thanks.

Comment: You do not have an array in the file.